# Cannot apply patch file using msdelta

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to apply patches using msdelta API of windows, and I wrote a program following the official documentation. But the program always returns an error, using the GetLastError function returns 0xd (The data is invalid.).

`C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-windows-win32k_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.674_none_1aec2f5c63bcf4f9\\win32k.sys` is a PE file and I checked its contents using the hex editor Hxd to make sure it is the correct PE file.
`C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-windows-win32k_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.674_none_1aec2f5c63bcf4f9\\r\\win32k.sys` is the patch file, I used Hxd to look at his content and found its first eight bytes are 91 8C DC 51 50 41 33 30, I know 91 8C DC 51 is `C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-windows-win32k_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.674_none_1aec2f5c63bcf4f9\\r\\win32k.sys`'s CRC32, 50 41 33 30 means PA30, I Guess that means its file format.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <msdelta.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "msdelta.lib")

int main()
{   
    DWORD dwNumRead = 0;

    HANDLE hSourceFile = CreateFileA(
        "C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-windows-win32k_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.674_none_1aec2f5c63bcf4f9\\win32k.sys",
        FILE_GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL
    );

    if (hSourceFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("Cannot open file.") << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD dwSourceBuferSize = GetFileSize(hSourceFile, NULL);
    LPVOID pSourceBuffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSourceBuferSize);
    ReadFile(
        hSourceFile,
        pSourceBuffer,
        dwSourceBuferSize,
        &dwNumRead,
        NULL
    );

    if (dwNumRead != dwSourceBuferSize)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("Cannot read file.") << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DELTA_INPUT Source;
    Source.Editable = TRUE;
    Source.lpStart = pSourceBuffer;
    Source.uSize = dwSourceBuferSize;

    HANDLE hDeltaFile = CreateFileA(
        "C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-windows-win32k_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.674_none_1aec2f5c63bcf4f9\\r\\win32k.sys",
        FILE_GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL
    );

    if (hDeltaFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("Cannot open file.") << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD dwDeltaBuferSize = GetFileSize(hDeltaFile, NULL);
    LPVOID pDeltaBuffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwDeltaBuferSize);
    ReadFile(
        hDeltaFile,
        pDeltaBuffer,
        dwDeltaBuferSize,
        &dwNumRead,
        NULL
    );

    if (dwNumRead != dwDeltaBuferSize)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("Cannot read file.") << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DELTA_INPUT Delta;
    Delta.Editable = TRUE;
    Delta.lpStart = pDeltaBuffer;
    Delta.uSize = dwDeltaBuferSize;

    DELTA_OUTPUT Output;
    BOOL bResult = ApplyDeltaB(
        DELTA_FLAG_NONE,
        Source,
        Delta,
        &Output
    );
    
    if (!bResult)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("{0:#x}", GetLastError()) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please call `GetLastError` **immediately** after you have determined that it will return meaningful data, with absolutely no intervening code.

Comment: Though the problem is likely as mundane as passing garbage values into `ApplyDeltaB`. Notably, `DELTA_OUTPUT Output` holds indeterminate values, and should probably be zero-initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetLastError() could return 0xd for one of the following reasons:

1. If possible, the version number does not match, for example, the 10.0.22621.674 patch requires the source file of 10.0.22621.*
2. When the CAD+PSF (https://github.com/Secant1006/PSFExtractor) extract out the type of Delta type is "RAW" (for example: The one described in the XML file that named express.psf.cix.xml: "`<File id="12" name="amd64_microsoft-composable-dragdrop.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.608_ar-sa_67bd2c905a6c0206\f\shellcomponents.dragdrop.ar-sa.pri" length="50" time="133028535950000000" attr="128"><Hash alg="SHA256" value="284D19A8418480222ACD5255A7A236E08C8C1AE67D8F0750FC63E9FE3DE766DC" /><Delta><Source type="RAW" offset="1848782" length="50"><Hash alg="SHA256" value="284D19A8418480222ACD5255A7A236E08C8C1AE67D8F0750FC63E9FE3DE766DC" /></Source></Delta></File>` "), you need to take the CRC32 of the first four bytes of the file, and then calculate the CRC32 of the file with the first four bytes removed, last pass the memory and size of the file with the first four bytes removed into ApplyDeltaB.

Like this:

```
if (strncmp(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pDeltaBuffer), "PA", 2)) {
        DWORD32 dwCRC32 = *(PDWORD)pDeltaBuffer;
        *(ULONG_PTR*)&pDeltaBuffer += 4;
        dwDeltaBuferSize -= 4;
        if (dwCRC32 != CRC32(PBYTE(pDeltaBuffer), dwDeltaBuferSize)) {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Also I recommend using GetDeltaInfoA and ApplyDeltaProvidedB. The first argument of ApplyDeltaProvidedB is passed to the DELTA_HEADER_INFO.Flags that GetDeltaInfoA gets

Like this:

```
DELTA_HEADER_INFO  dhi = { 0 };
BOOL bResult = GetDeltaInfoA(szDeltaFilePath, 
    &dhi
);
if (!bResult) {
    return 0;
}

PVOID buff = HeapAlloc(
    GetProcessHeap(),
    HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,
    dhi.TargetSize
);

bResult = ApplyDeltaProvidedB(
    dhi.Flags,
    Source,
    Delta,
    buff,
    dhi.TargetSize
);
```